# Firestore security rule match path to a field in dictionary

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Let's say I have this Firestore below user object with fields name, address, and cars (note only user is a collection).

```
user {
      name: "John Smith"
      address: '123 Firebase Road, Firestore CA, 10000"
      cars: {
               asfdfsd811r9UAdfasdf1: {
                       name: "Ford Explorer"
                       carSold: false,
                       salesComment: "This is the best SUV in the world"
               },
               12342342ADSfas! :{
                        name:" Testla Modal X"
                        carPrice:false,
                       salesComment: "This is the best electric car in the world"
               }
      }
}
```

I want to set a security rule to enforce the client libraries can only edit salesComment, but nothing else in this user collection object, how do I do it? I set up a matching path like below, but it doesn't work :( . Can you set up a match path to field dictionary, like in this case, cars? Does match and variableId pattern only apply to collections only.

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /user/{userId} {
              match /cars/{carId}/salesComment {
                    allow write: if request.auth.uid == userId;
              }
               allow read: if request.auth.uid == userId;
        }
```

Comment: You can't use the names of document fields in the match path.  You will have to write code in the rule to check that fields data is only being modified the way you want.

Comment: Hi Doug, big fan of your Firebase videos (watched all the videos about promises over 3 times). re: can't user names of document fields in the match path, so is it even possible to check if the user is editing specific key of the dictionary which is in dictionary of the document field? So in this case, is it not possible to only allow the user to edit salesComment key of the dictionary which is in dictionary of the document field cars? So you cannot even use regex like match /user/{restOfPath=**} {
      restOfPath.matches('cars/.+/salesComment/.+'), right?

Comment: The challenge is there is an unknown key - carId - which is unknown and it is not possible to iterate through dictionary in Firestore (or RTDB) security rules. Only user is collection. I just made up this example for simplicity, but it seems it is not possible to do what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: Like I can do (request.resource.data.diff(resource.data).changedKeys().hasOnly(["cars"]) and allow the user to edit everything in the cars field of the user collection. But that's not what I want. I want to enforce that the user can only edit specific subfield of that cars field.

Comment: @DougStevenson plz let me know if this is possible. If not possible, tell me too. For now I let the user just edit the whole field of the collection. This particular security rule limitation is pretty minor as far as my project is concerned. But I can propose this as a feature to Firebase since it is weird that you can update field using paths like user/cars/{carId}/salesComment but you cannot match it in security rules.

Comment: I just want to set Firestore security rule so that a field of a dictionary of a dictionary of a dictionary can be edited. If the user isn't editing that particular field, Firestore security rule should deny access. I just started a bounty as I have another place where I need this.

Comment: I could get the keys and iterate through them by checking every index so I can iterate through the cars dictionary (since I have a limit of how many cars or other objects I can have - cars are just in this example :). That's what I just did. Still have to test if it works or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Workaround approach: Custom functions

You can't use match with internal fields, instead you must make use of the [`rules.List`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.List), [`rules.Map`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.Map) and [`rules.Set`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.Set) objects.

It's important to note that rules are static and do not have the ability to iterate over lists (such as using `forEach`, `map`, etc). This can be overcome by using `someList.size() <= position` to check if the list is long enough before performing the element comparison. Unfortunately, this must be hard-coded as you'll see below.

One goal of these rules is that they should be able to be combined with other rules on the same document. i.e. the "cars" map should be restricted but you should still be able to update the "name" and "address" fields.

Throughout this section, the variables are going to be pretty verbose for ease-of-understanding (such as including type information). Rename them to suit your style.

Disclaimer: While this first set of rules works, it's janky and overly specific - not recommended for production use.

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    // assert no changes or that only "salesComment" was changed
    function isCarEditAllowed(afterCarMap, beforeCarMap) {
      return afterCarMap.diff(beforeCarMap).affectedKeys().size() == 0
          || afterCarMap.diff(beforeCarMap).affectedKeys().hasOnly(["salesComment"]);
    }

    // assert that if this car exists that it has allowed changes
    function isCarAtPosValid(afterCarsList, beforeCarsList, position) {
      return afterCarsList.size() <= position // returns true when car doesn't exist
          || isCarEditAllowed(afterCarsList[position], beforeCarsList[position])
    }

    function areCarEditsAllowed(afterDataMap, beforeDataMap) {
      return afterDataMap.get("cars", false) != false // cars field exists after
          && beforeDataMap.get("cars", false) != false // cars field exists before
          && afterDataMap.cars.size() == beforeDataMap.cars.size() // cars field is same length
          && isCarAtPosValid(afterDataMap.cars, beforeDataMap.cars, 0)
          && isCarAtPosValid(afterDataMap.cars, beforeDataMap.cars, 1)
          && isCarAtPosValid(afterDataMap.cars, beforeDataMap.cars, 2)
          && isCarAtPosValid(afterDataMap.cars, beforeDataMap.cars, 3)
          && isCarAtPosValid(afterDataMap.cars, beforeDataMap.cars, 4)
    }

    match /carUsers/{userId} {
      allow read: if request.auth.uid == userId;

      allow write: if request.auth.uid == userId
                   && areCarEditsAllowed(request.resource.data, resource.data)
    }
  }
}
```

Now that the above rules work, they can be improved by abstracting the steps into a set of reusable custom functions.

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    /* Custom Functions: Restrict map changes */

    function mapHasAllowedChanges(afterMap, beforeMap, setOfWhitelistedKeys) {
      return afterMap.diff(beforeMap).affectedKeys().size() == 0 // no changes
          || setOfWhitelistedKeys.hasAll(afterMap.diff(beforeMap).affectedKeys()) // only named keys may be changed
    }

    function mapInListHasAllowedChanges(afterList, beforeList, setOfWhitelistedKeys, position) {
      return afterList.size() <= position // returns true when element doesn't exist
          || mapHasAllowedChanges(afterList[position], beforeList[position], setOfWhitelistedKeys)
    }

    function listOfMapsHasAllowedChanges(afterList, beforeList, setOfWhitelistedKeys) {
      return mapInListHasAllowedChanges(afterList, beforeList, setOfWhitelistedKeys, 0)
          && mapInListHasAllowedChanges(afterList, beforeList, setOfWhitelistedKeys, 1)
          && mapInListHasAllowedChanges(afterList, beforeList, setOfWhitelistedKeys, 2)
          && mapInListHasAllowedChanges(afterList, beforeList, setOfWhitelistedKeys, 3)
          && mapInListHasAllowedChanges(afterList, beforeList, setOfWhitelistedKeys, 4)
    }

    function largeListOfMapsHasAllowedChanges(afterList, beforeList, setOfWhitelistedKeys) {
      return mapInListHasAllowedChanges(afterList, beforeList, setOfWhitelistedKeys, 0)
          && mapInListHasAllowedChanges(afterList, beforeList, setOfWhitelistedKeys, 1)
          && mapInListHasAllowedChanges(afterList, beforeList, setOfWhitelistedKeys, 2)
          && mapInListHasAllowedChanges(afterList, beforeList, setOfWhitelistedKeys, 3)
          && mapInListHasAllowedChanges(afterList, beforeList, setOfWhitelistedKeys, 4)
          && mapInListHasAllowedChanges(afterList, beforeList, setOfWhitelistedKeys, 5)
          && mapInListHasAllowedChanges(afterList, beforeList, setOfWhitelistedKeys, 6)
          && mapInListHasAllowedChanges(afterList, beforeList, setOfWhitelistedKeys, 7)
          && mapInListHasAllowedChanges(afterList, beforeList, setOfWhitelistedKeys, 8)
          && mapInListHasAllowedChanges(afterList, beforeList, setOfWhitelistedKeys, 9)
    }

    function namedListWithSameSizeExists(listPath) {
      return request.resource.data.get(listPath, false) != false
          && resource.data.get(listPath, false) != false
          && request.resource.data.get(listPath, {}).size() == resource.data.get(listPath, {}).size()
    }

    function namedListOfMapsWithSameSizeExistsWithAllowedChanges(listPath, setOfWhitelistedKeys) {
      return namedListWithSameSizeExists(listPath)
          && listOfMapsHasAllowedChanges(request.resource.data.get(listPath, {}), resource.data.get(listPath, {}), setOfWhitelistedKeys)
    }

    /* Rules */

    match /carUsers/{userId} {
      allow read: if request.auth.uid == userId;

      allow write: if request.auth.uid == userId
                   && namedListOfMapsWithSameSizeExistsWithAllowedChanges("cars", ["salesComment"].toSet())
    }
  }
}
```

Note: The above rules do not assert that the whitelisted keys were not deleted. To ensure that the listed keys are present after the change, you will need to replace the `mapHasAllowedChanges` function with:

```
function mapHasAllowedChanges(afterMap, beforeMap, setOfWhitelistedKeys) {
      return afterMap.diff(beforeMap).affectedKeys().size() == 0 // no changes
          || (setOfWhitelistedKeys.hasAll(afterMap.diff(beforeMap).affectedKeys()) // only named keys may be changed
          && afterMap.keys().toSet().hasAll(setOfWhitelistedKeys)) // all named keys must exist
    }
```

### Recommended approach: Move to cars to subcollection

The above rules are quite complex, and can be simplified if you move the cars to their own collection and make use of [`rules.Map#diff`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.MapDiff).

The below code will only allow a write to take place if the user owns that car document and is also modifying only the `salesComment` key (modify = add/change/remove).

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /user/{userId} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == userId;

      match /cars/{carId} {
        allow read: if request.auth.uid == userId; // Firestore rules don't cascade to subcollections, so this is also needed

        allow write: if request.auth.uid == userId
                     && request.resource.data.diff(resource.data).affectedKeys().hasOnly(["salesComment"]);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If you require that `salesComment` must be present after a write (add/change allowed - but not remove), you can also ensure that is still present using [`k in x`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.Map).

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /user/{userId} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == userId;

      match /cars/{carId} {
        allow read: if request.auth.uid == userId; // Firestore rules don't cascade to subcollections, so this is also needed

        allow write: if request.auth.uid == userId
                     && "salesComment" in request.resource.data
                     && request.resource.data.diff(resource.data).affectedKeys().hasOnly(["salesComment"]);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: First one wouldn't work because only user is a collection. Car is not a collection. Car is a key of a dictionary for the user collection.

Second one wouldn't work, would it? When user edits salesComment field, Wouldn't request.resource.data.diff(resource.data).affectedKeys() be returning "cars", not "salesComment"? since salesComment is inside dictionary of a dictionary.

Comment: I think I have to get all keys and just hard look up index at 0, 1, 2 etc. That's the only, sad way to do this.

Comment: @coolcool1994 I see that I initially misinterpreted the question. I have done some research and added my findings to my answer.

Comment: I did something similar. I awarded you the bounty. I haven't tested it yet though. I will accept it once I check if it works.

Comment: I confirmed that this works. The only caveat is you need to have fixed number of cars. If you have infinite number of cars, there is no way to enforce specific field being edited - but I guess this is a point of having it inside a document otherwise it should be another collection. Use diffs in every level and check for the hasOnly to enforce the rule. I have it as this working in my project.

Comment: You can limit it by enforcing that `request.resource.data.cars.size() < LIMIT`. If you have more than 10 or so entries, you should really consider moving to using a subcollection. That subcollection could be set up so that it is one car per document or an array of say 10 cars - so the first doc is 0-9, the second 10-19, etc.

Comment: If you expect that you will need all the cars in one hit, you are better off storing the cars in the Realtime Database instead where you can then use the `match` rule as you expected above.